# How can I access the Rails javascript files on the backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a javascript/client application that uses a number of templates that I want to make available to a model (for server-side rendering of JS/HTML).

How can I access the javascript files from my model? Ideally I'm also able to access the precompiled 'application.js' bundle.

For instance, If I have the following manifest at app/assets/javascripts

application.js

```
//= require libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
//= require libs/bootstrap.min.js
//= require libs/underscore.min.js
```

And I want to grab the resulting compiled application.js from say a user Model:

```
# Render a version of the client site on the server
class SiteRender < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Do the rendering
    # Grab all necessary assets/Javascripts/HTML to produce the rendering
    def self.render

       # How can I grab the compiled application.js, application.css, etc as RAW BYTES?
    end

end
```

I'm aware that I can grab individual assets like so:

SiteRenderApp::Application.assets.find_asset('libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js').body

However I require access to the compiled application.js manifest (since I have special requires instructions that get run in the asset pipeline.

**More background**

I require access to the same Javascript template files on the server (*.JST) as those used by the front-end.   My server-side process is simulating the front-end and therefore requires it to be fed the same Javascript source files as found on the client.

Thanks,

Comment: Why in earth would you do this? You don't need javascript to render html.

Comment: If you want to pre-render, then use caching or a headless browser. Your models should not know anything about the view layer.

Comment: It's not unreasonable to want to obtain the raw bytes of the compiled javascript/client assets on the backend.         I know the model should not know about the view.  However the 'model' in this case is a server-side rendering process that needs the SAME libraries that the front-end does.   I called it model since Rails does not natively have a 'Service Object' concept (which is how I organized my code, but left that detail out for SO users)